# Do AWS user-defined tags for cost incur any hourly or monthly price

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing

I'm planning to make user of user-defined tags for billing to get my AWS resources grouped and organized in terms of generating daily and monthly reports.

My question is am I going to incur any cost for the number of user-defined tags that I create and use? I was not able to find any information related to this in AWS documentation and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: tags themselves don't cost anything.  I don't think setting up cost and usage reports costs anything more than the s3 operations, which cost very little.  Tagging and using for cost tracking is the standard way of doing it in AWS so you're on the right track.

Answer (score 4):

There is no charge for tags. Tags are the best way to categorize AWS spend by resource, environment, application, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times there is **no** additional cost, but there is an **exception** with **S3 Object Tags**, as they do have an additional cost.

From the official AWS Documentation (2023-11-19):

> US East (Ohio): S3 Object Tagging $0.01 per 10,000 tags per month

Link to documentation (under the "Management & Insights" tab):

- https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/